# Ansible playbook syntax error with tasks:

Tags: ansible

I just started experimenting with ansible and I am trying to write my first simple playbook.
But I am getting a syntax error with the task keywork,

```
---
name: add ansible user
hosts: all
become: true
become_method: sudo
become_user:root

 tasks:
 - user:
    name: ansible
    groups: ansible
```

When I run this get the following:

```
utility:~/scripts/ansible# ansible-playbook --check add-ansible-user.yml 
ERROR! Syntax Error while loading YAML.


The error appears to have been in '/root/scripts/ansible/add-ansible-user.yml': line 8, column 7, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:

 tasks:
      ^ here
```

From searching I belive the best bet is that I have an indent problem, but nomatter how I have tried to change it up, I cant get it too work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

---

```
 - name: add ansible user
   hosts: all
   become: true
   become_method: sudo
   become_user: root

   tasks:
     - user:
       name: ansible
       groups: ansible
```

It's indeed the indentation problem. Please try the code written above.

Answer (score 0):

Facing same issue, by making correct Indent spacing able to resolve it
As ref below

```
---
- name: my ansible
  hosts: webserver
  remote_user: root
  become: true
  tasks:
        - name: intall httpd
          yum:
               name: httpd
               state: latest
        - name: run httpd
          service:
               name: httpd
               state: started
        - name: create content
          copy:
               content: “Congratulation on installing ansible”
               dest: /var/www/html/index.html
```

Answer (score -5):

The problem is here:

```
become_user:root
```

You need a space between `:` and `root`

```
become_user: root
```